# Exposing an n-tier application deployed in Azure AKS

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I am quite novice in this field, so don't be offensed by my question.
I am interested to get a working example for the following situation:

Spring application, called backend, a React application, called frontend and a Keycloak.

and all these are deployed into an Azure kubernetes service.

What is the best structure to

1. expose them to the internet
2. ensure the connection between the backend and the keycloak, inside of AKS

This exposure should be using a custom DNS name, resolvable from my browser, like these:

```
api.abc.org ---> backend
www.abc.org ---> frontend
kc.abc.org ---> Keycloak
```

Best regards,
KI

Answer (score 0):

I have similar deployments (not exactly the same as my frontends are Angular and my K8s is managed at OVH, but this doesn't change much). Here is how I proceed:

- the OpenID Provider (Keycloak) is available from `https://oidc.c4-soft.com/auth/`. It is used as SSO for several apps, so it has its own DNS name and publicly exposed service
- each app (frontend & backend) is served through a `spring-cloud-gateway` instance. This gateway is available from `https://bff.demo.c4-soft.com`
- the services for front and back ends are internal to the cluster. Only the gateway service is exposed to the internet. The routes are for instance:

  - `https://bff.demo.c4-soft.com/ui/**`: equivalent for what you labeled `www.abc.org` in your question
  - `https://bff.demo.c4-soft.com/bff/**`: equivalent for what you labeled `api.abc.org` `in your question

Serving both frontend and backend with the same gateway removes the need for any CORS configuration (from the browser perspective, all requests have the same origin: the gateway).

The `spring-cloud-gateway` instance is configured as **B**ackend **F**or **F**rontend:

- configured as OAuth2 client (with login and logout)
- with `TokenRelay=` filter. Requests are authorized with session cookie between the frontend and the gateway and with a Bearer JWT between the gateway and resource servers (REST APIs). This `TokenRelay` does the translation auto-magically.

Complete sample  deployed [here](https://bff.demo.c4-soft.com/ui/) with source code [there](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/bff).